# PHP loop counter issue with bootstrap slider

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, loops, foreach

I'm using Bootstrap slider and want to display 3 items per slide generated from a foreach loop.

This loop counter keeps adding and extra <div> at the end of the loop, there are 6 items in the loop so I get an empty slide. How can I fix this?

```
<?php if (database_querySelect($sql,$rows)) {

$spCounter = 0;

?>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4><?php print translate("Related Products"); ?></h4>
    </div>

<div id="relatedSlider" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <?php foreach($searchresults["products"] as $product): ?>

        <?php include("html/search/style1.php"); ?>

        <?php if(($spCounter) % 3 == 0) : ?>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $spCounter++; endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>


  </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="item">
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $spCounter++; endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

The div with class item is inside foreach loop, and you have conditional statement that passes after every 3rd counter.